# How to sort a list in Scala when objects are of dynamic?

Tags: list, scala, sorting

I have the following hierarchy in Scala

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
case class Child1(alpha: MyAbstractClass, points: Int) extends MyAbstractClass
case class Child2(beta: Char, points: Int) extends MyAbstractClass
```

Now I have a list
List(MyAbstractClass type objects ... either Chil1 or Child2 )

I want to sort the above list based on points. How to write this in Scala?

Answer (score 4):

You should add a method called `points` to your base class:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass { def points:Int }
```

The subclasses already implement this method, since they are case classes, so you don't need to change them.

```
case class Child1(alpha: MyAbstractClass, points: Int) extends MyAbstractClass
case class Child2(beta: Char, points: Int) extends MyAbstractClass
```

Then you can sort the list using this method.

```
println(List(Child2('a',0),Child1(Child2('b',2),3)).sortBy(_.points))
```

Comment: Kim Stebel - MyAbstractClass is provided by someone else so I can't add def points:Int to it .

Comment: If you really can't change the class, you can always insert another one into the hierarchy between `MyAbstractClass` and your case classes.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use your solution for another situation .

Answer (score 3):

You can use structural typing helps you here

```
list.sortBy{
  case x: {def points: Int} => x.points
}
```

sortBy takes a function that when applied to each element will return the value to sort by. The case statement says "if x is a type that has a "point" method, then return x.points

Answer (score 1):

Used a slightly different approach 
1) Without adding points var to parent class
2) Without changing the hierarchy of classes

list containing objects of type MyAbstractClass

```
list.sortWith((x,y) => point(x) < point(y))

def point(mylist: MyAbstractClass): Int = mylist match {
case Child1(a, p) => p
case Child2(b, p) => p
}
```